# Magento CE 1.8: Varnish won't Purge URLs

Tags: magento, debian, varnish, varnish-vcl

we are running Magento CE 1.8 on Debian Root with the following configuration:

```
Nginx --> Varnish 3.0 --> Apache
```

We have installed the "PageSpeed powered by Varnish"-Extension (but it's not a 3rd party module problem, we've got the same problem on other servers)

Now the Problem:
If we change some Products, delete Products or something, Varnish won't Purge those URLs (i think so). *I get an 504 Gateway Timeout when editing products.*
If I restart the varnish service, everything is ok - but we can't trigger purging via magento backend.

So i checked my /etc/default/varnish file for checking deamon_opts:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :8080 \
         -T localhost:6081 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -S /etc/varnish/secret \
         -s malloc,4G"
```

It's not a default varnish config, because nginx in front of varnish uses Port 80. So Varnish has 8080 and Apache 80 again (only internal).

Varnish Admin Port is 6081, this is saved in the PageSpeed-Extension, too.
Okay, let's have a look at default.vcl (some parts):

```
backend default {
 .host = "127.0.0.1";
 .port = "80";
}
```

// I think this is ok, let's look at acl purge to allow magento purging URLs:

```
acl purge {
"localhost";
"127.0.0.1";
}
```

//Some lines of VCL-stuff// now find purging in "sub vcl_recv":

```
# purge request
if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
        error 405 "Not allowed.";
    }
    ban("obj.http.X-Purge-Host ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Host + " && obj.http.X-Purge-URL ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Regex + " && obj.http.Content-Type ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Content-Type);
    error 200 "Purged.";
}
```

Okay, now the problem details. It has been a while since i checked some kind of log, which said something like "Timeout" (after 15 seconds) but i forgot which tool i used. The issue happens if i want to **edit products** in Magento backend. I click save and it loads and loads and loads. Then i get **504 Gateway Time-Out** in my Browser.

varnishlog says (at the moment of editing a product)

```
0 CLI          - Rd ping
0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1417774882 1.0
0 CLI          - Rd ping
0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1417774885 1.0
0 CLI          - Rd ping
0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1417774963 1.0
0 CLI          - Rd ping
0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1417774966 1.0
0 CLI          - Rd ping
0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1417774969 1.0
14 BackendClose b default
18 BackendOpen  b default 127.0.0.1 34992 127.0.0.1 80
```

It seems to me that magento backend can't trigger the purging process. In the Log (the one with the timeout) were the URLs which should be purged. I think there is some kind of connection-fail between magento and varnish (CLI?)

How can I troubleshoot the specific problem?
Are there any tools, commands or tricks?
I've got no clue what's the problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Magento 1.8.1 and above versions aren't compatible by default with the Varnish cache. I would recommend using Redis instead. At the same time Nginx --> Varnish 3.0 --> Apache configuration seems a bit absurd. It should be Varnish 3.0 --> Nginx --> PHP-FPM without Apache. In your specific case check this guide for a correct Varnish 3.0 config file. https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/12/creating-a-faster-magento-store-part-one-server-setup/

Comment: Hello, Nginx-> varnish -> apache is performing fine, no reason to change that. 
We've got the same problem on another machine running Magento CE 1.7! So i think its no Magento issue. Varnish is running, the Store is super fast!
Redis is no alternative for varnish, it's maybe an alternative for memcached. We need to get varnish running.

I tested the vcl's in your link a few days ago. most of the files is similar with my vcl. it's the same extension.

Comment: Both nginx and varnish can serve as proxies to back end services. Your current implementation is using nginx as the proxy. Have you specified proxy_pass for Nginx? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Answer (score 0):

This command will purge all Url's

varnishadm "ban req.url ~ /"